# Pivot with Page as pivotItem

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to create `Pivot` in my app with 4 `PivotItem` that every `PivoeItem` is phone page and will be manage with is own Class.

This is how i build my pivot page without page for every page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
  <!--Pivot Control-->
  <controls:Pivot Title="my application">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
      <Grid>
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <!--Pivot item two-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
      <Grid>
    </controls:PivotItem>
  </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Can i make `PivotItem` with Page? (`Xaml` + `cs`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you need the same content in two places (eg: as a PivotItem and also as a standalone Page), I'd wrap the functionality in a custom UserControl which you can use on both.

Comment: I want to build Pivot that every item is Page, it is not possible? i want it because every page have a different attitude.